# Receiving HTTP Post Data on php

Tags: php, c++, wininet

okay good evening

i been having problems recieving data from http request from a C++ program

I use `Wininet`

```
InternetOpenA()
InternetConnect()
HttpOpenRequest()
HttpSendRequest()
```

now the good news is it sends the program to the php file, now no worries all work fine there

when i do a code like this to get the POST data

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents(php://input);
$fp = fopen("log.txt","a+");
fwrite($fp,$data);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

it gets the data and saves to text file. but when i do the following

```
<?php
$data = urldecode($_POST['info']);
$fp = fopen("log.txt","a+");
fwrite($fp,$data);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

it just creates the log.txt and doesnt save any data inside it. Started to think this is a php problem, but every thing i tried just fails... what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you print_r($_POST);? Are you sure that you're posting data with the correct content type? (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

Comment: yes i am using the post i found here http://securityblog.gr/1823/http-post-and-get-requests-with-wininet-and-c/

Comment: Anyways, just so you can narrow down the issue, `$_POST` empty or not? Also edit in your C++ code, the example you linked doesn't send a field named `info`.

Comment: $_POST is empty

Comment: Alright, you need to edit in your C++ code. You've edited the example right? Because if you just ran the example code, you wouldn't get an `info` POST field.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the PHP code, show us your C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

From experience, fopen has caused alot of errors for me, it just doesnt always work with certain aspects. 
Create a mysql database and save the log data there and you can create a page/ connect to it with your C++ program to get the logs.

Comment: if it doesnt show in empty text, you ever tried and it saved in db, when it didnt show in text file?

Answer (score 0):

If you get data from `php://input`, but `$_POST` is empty, then your POST data is **NOT** in `key=value` format. If PHP can't find any `key=value` data, then it can't build `$_POST` for you. $_POST is an array like any other, and all data going into it **MUST** have a key. No key, no array entry.

Comment: how do i go about this ?

Comment: You conform to the HTTP standards for formatting a POST-style form submission, or you parse whatever you read from php://input yourself.